# Event Information Page

Tags: civievent

I am trying to change a logo that appears on my event information page (https://integrativeonc.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=30). The area in the lower right that says "empowered by ADG creative" is what I am trying to edit. I cannot find where to edit this in Civi. Can someone assist?

Best regards,
Erika

Answer (score 2):

i think ADG have swopped out the civicrm logo with their own. If so then you can disable this on your system as a whole by going to /civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1 and turn off the 'empowered by civicrm' setting

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!  I agree with Pete about how the logo is being added.  If you want to disable it on all public forms then change the option to 'No'.

However, if you want to keep 'empowered by' but change the logo then find the file `templates/adgcreative/css/civicrm.css` and change the image file on line 3 that currently reads `url(../images/adg-creative-sm.png)`.  Alternatively comment out that first rule to go back to the normal CiviCRM logo.

Comment: nice double act we have going here.

Comment: This is extremely helpful! Thank you for replying so quickly as my problem is now solved!!